# only return records count() = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table called myTable

```
Posting Date|Item No_|Entry Type|
2015-01-13|1234|1
2015-01-13|1234|1
2015-01-12|1234|1
2015-01-12|5678|1
2015-02-12|4567|1
```

What I want, is only return result where a [Item No_] is ind the table 1 time.
So in this example of my table, i only want to return  [Item No_] 5678 and 4567, because there only are one record in it. And then ignore [Item No_] 1234

This is my SQL i have tried, but something is wrong. Can anyone help me?

```
SELECT [Item No_], [Posting Date], COUNT([Item No_]) AS Antal
FROM         myTable
GROUP BY [Entry Type], [Posting Date], [Item No_]
HAVING      ([Entry Type] = 1) AND (COUNT([Item No_]) = 1)
ORDER BY [Posting Date] DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Posting Date` from `group by`

```
SELECT [Item No_],Entry Type, COUNT([Item No_]) AS Antal
FROM    myTable
GROUP BY [Entry Type], [Item No_]
HAVING   COUNT([Item No_]) = 1
```

or if you want other details use a `subquery`

```
SELECT [Item No_],
       Entry   Type,
       Posting Date
FROM   myTable a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   myTable b
               where a.[Item No_]=b.[Item No_]
               GROUP  BY [Entry Type],
                         [Item No_]
               HAVING Count(1) = 1) 
ORDER BY [Posting Date] DESC
```

or `window function`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT [Item No_],
                [Posting Date],
                [Entry Type],
                Row_number()OVER (Partition BY [Entry Type], [Item No_] ORDER BY [Item No_]) RN
         FROM   myTable)
SELECT *
FROM   cte a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   cte b
                   WHERE  a.[Item No_] = b.[Item No_]
                          AND rn > 1) 
ORDER BY [Posting Date] DESC
```

Comment: Well, you have to remove it from the selected columns too, as it's not an aggregate, you can't select the Posting Date column unless you also group by it.

Comment: I have tried this, but then get this error Column "myTable.Posting Date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @KevinLund - just remove `order by` updated check now

Comment: @NoDisplayName But i need my `Order By` :/

Comment: @KevinLund - use the other two queries

Answer (score 3):

```
select [Item No_]
from myTable
group by [Item No_]
having count(*)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_Number()` in Sql Server

```
select * from (
SELECT [Item No_], [Posting Date], 
Row_Number() over (Parition by [Item No_]
order by [Item No]) RN
FROM         myTable
)D
where D.RN=1
```